# share folders using apex

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-sharing, folder

Looking for a feature(apex) to share folders to users/groups etc using apex. We have REST based APIs to do. Just wondering if we have anything like that in Apex.

Following are working fine:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_folders_shares.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_folders_shares_by_id.htm

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is directly possible with Apex as of Today, as [FolderShare](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.194.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_foldershare.htm) Object is not exposed. There is an idea here and worth voting for it : https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdoa2UAB/share-report-folder-object-visibility

You have to use either [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_folders_shares.htm) or [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_foldershare.htm) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @saroj..